# How do I programmatically find the core version?

Tags: 8

How do I programmatically find the Drupal core version running a site?

Answer (score 4):

I found this example in MetatagNodeTranslationTest.

To find the drupal version in your code,

```
\Drupal::VERSION
```

will return it.

If you need to compare

```
if (floatval(\Drupal::VERSION) <= 8.3) {
  // do some stuff.
}
```

Comment: This will not work if Drupal 8.10 is released.  `version_compare()` is described as being for PHP versions, but should work for semantic versioning in D8.

Comment: Example: If the current version is equal to or higher than 9.4 `version_compare(\Drupal::VERSION, '9.4', '>=')`